# how to show this in shell screen in color

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I have this content in an email

```
[0;32minfo: Applying configuration version '1421674528' [0m
```

I know it is something with color coded text in shell terminal. How to get it shown in color? Any simple way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by “get it shown in color”, but you can copy-paste this to your shell:

```
[0;32minfo: Applying configuration version '1421674528' [0m
```

then, add the “echo” command and quotes:

```
echo '[0;32minfo: Applying configuration version '1421674528' [0m'
```

and finally add the missing escapes (ie. “\033”) before each escape sequence:

```
echo '\033[0;32minfo: Applying configuration version '1421674528' \033[0m'
```

Here, your text should display in green.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to insert the missing codes:

```
echo "[0;32minfo: Applying configuration version '1421674528' [0m" | sed 's/\[/\x1b[/g'
```

Comment: Does it show on your terminal? mine is still shown as usual, no coloring at all. what might be wrong?

Comment: @QiangLi: I see it in green. What OS/terminal do you use?

Comment: mac osx terminal. but when i use an amazon ec2 instance terminal, it worked! so what's the config parameter that I need to use for mac terminal?

Comment: @QiangLi: Try setting the TERM variable to `xterm` or `xterm-256color`.